# Perl equivalent of pyephem?

Tags: python, perl, pyephem

What's the Perl equivalent of [pyephem](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/)?

Since pyephem is based on a C library(?), I'm guessing someone's created a Perl version too?

Comment: please tell us what you want to do, perhaps there are ways to accomplish them. I doubt there is an exact port as though the module in question is coded in C it is not a wrapper for an external C library.

Comment: Ultimately, I'm trying to find the time of the next moon/sun rise/set or twilight at a given location for a given time EVEN IF that event doesn't occur in the next 24 hours. For example, sunset in Barrow AK in mid-June will actually occur many weeks later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked out libnova? It's quite powerful. There's a Perl wrapper for that: [Astro::Nova](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Astro-Nova/lib/Astro/Nova.pm).

Quoting the documentation below, one of these could do exactly what you want. The Perl docs are relatively sparse because I didn't want to reproduce the entire library documentation for the wrapper. The functions are mostly similar to how the work in C. Exceptions from that should be documented. The [main libnova docs](http://libnova.sourceforge.net/) have all the details.

```
(int $status, Astro::Nova::RstTime $rst) =
  get_object_rst(double JD, Astro::Nova::LnLatPosn observer, Astro::Nova::EquPosn object)
(int $status, Astro::Nova::RstTime $rst) =
  get_object_rst_horizon(double JD, Astro::Nova::LnLatPosn observer,
                         Astro::Nova::EquPosn object, double horizon)
(int $status, Astro::Nova::RstTime $rst) =
  get_object_next_rst(double JD, Astro::Nova::LnLatPosn observer, Astro::Nova::EquPosn object)
(int $status, Astro::Nova::RstTime $rst) =
  get_object_next_rst_horizon(double JD, Astro::Nova::LnLatPosn observer,
                              Astro::Nova::EquPosn object, double horizon)
```

Comment: It turns out Astro::Nova isn't quite as complete as pyephem. Another workaround is Inline::Python which lets you write Python code directly in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start here:

[Perl Astro Modules](http://search.cpan.org/~cphil/Astro/)

Comment: I've looked at many Perl Astro modules, including Astro::Sunrise and Astro::Coord::ECI, but none give me minute-to-minute agreement with NOAA's results (Astro::Sunrise comes close, but can be off by a few minutes AND fails when there is either a sunrise OR a sunset, but not both).